# Accessing row from a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a R dataFrame as:

```
Serial_N       voltage       current
   B              10            nan
   B              10            nan
   B              14            nan
   C              12            nan
   D              40            nan
   .               .             .
   AB             12            nan
```

I would like to loop through the elements from the voltage where the serial number is B.  I tried this:

```
for (i in 1:length)
{
  df[Serial_N==B,]$voltage[i]
}
```

but it does not work. Any suggestions without using a temporary variable?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you need a loop. What do you want to do with the voltages?

You can extract all the voltages where the `Serial_N == B` using basic subsetting with `[`

```
v <- df[df$Serial_N=="B", ]$voltage
```

Then do what you want with the voltages v

---

If you really are after a loop, your structure will be something like

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[i, ]$Serial_N == "B"
    # .. do other stuff..
}
```

Where your loop variable `i` is used to select one row at a time. You then compare the `Serial_N` value of that row to `"B"`

You then need to decide what you want to do with each row.

Comment: Any reason to use `df[df$Serial_N=="B", ]$voltage` instead of just `df$voltage[df$Serial_N=="B"]` or even `df[,"voltage"][df$Serial_N=="B"]` ? The first case is subsetting the entire `df` to a selection of rows, and then subsetting a single variable out of that result. It might have minimal impact most of the time, but could cause copying of large data I think.

Comment: @thelatemail - It's more from habit than actually thinking about it - and I know this isn't the first time you've pointed this out to me ;-)

Comment: Whoops... apologies for the broken record from me then! I forget who and what I comment on as time goes on. As I said, it's far from a big issue. Have a good one. :-)

Comment: @thelatemail No worries; I need to keep being reminded of better ways so I can improve myself

Answer (score 3):

You can select all voltages from rows where serial number is B, then iterate through them:

```
for(voltage in df$voltage[df$Serial_N=="B"]){print(voltage)}
```

Or you can iterate through indexes of rows having serial number B, then use the index and voltage field

```
for(i in which(df$Serial_N=="B")){print(CC[i,"voltage"])}
```